# How is the window.innerHeight derived of the minimal view?

Tags: javascript, ios8, mobile-safari

This is about the minimal view (ie., when you touch-drag enter "fullscreen"):

- When viewport width is 320, then `window.innerHeight` is 529.
- When viewport width is 640, then `window.innerHeight` is 1057.

Notice that viewport increased twice, but `window.innerHeight` did not (it should have been 1058 = 529 * 2).

Answer (score 1):

I do not have an in-depth understanding of the issue, but I am guessing it has to do with mapping of logical pixels to physical pixels. I'd like to share my findings/solution, in case anyone else stumbles across a related issue.

I am using proportion to deduct the `innerHeight` at a specific viewport width.

To build the proportion, I am using an arbitrary third viewport that is greater
than the other two. The `innerHeight` of the viewport in the proportion is derived through trial.

When viewport width is 1280 (320 * 4), then innerHeight is 2114.

```
1280; 2114
320; x      = Math.round(528.5) = 529

1280; 2114
640; x      = 1057
```

This allows us to get the `innerHeight` of the fullscreen page for an arbitrary viewport width.